# No funciona desactivar y activar Boton con Js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estoy intentado hacer que un boton es requerido, me explico: el usuario tiene que dar click al boton para poder que se realice una funcion. Ya que si no da click no me guarda el registro. Ademas ese boton hace un calculo en js  y por eso encesito que el usuario tiene que hacer click.

El boton es type button y tiene el id="calcular", he intentado con colocarle required directamente en html del boton del submit y un id="guardar" que tiene el atributo disabled que tambien en la funcion de calcular este me lo habilite pero tampoco funciona.

este es e archivo `create.blade.php`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pcantidad">
                Cantidad
            </label>
            <input class="form-control calcular" id="pcantidad" name="pcantidad" min="1" placeholder="Cantidad" required
                type="text" onkeypress='return validaNumeros(event)' min="1" oninput="escribir()">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pinteres">
                Interes
            </label>
            <input class="form-control calcular" id="pinteres" name="pinteres"  placeholder="interes" type="text"
                onkeypress='return validaNumeros(event)' required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 ">
        <div class="form-group text-center">
            <label for="">
                Obtener el total
            </label>
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="calcular" type="button">
                Calcular
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-responsive" id="detalles">
            <thead style="background-color: #9EDFF5">
                <th>
                    Opciones
                </th>
                <th>
                    Subtotal
                </th>
                <th>
                    Total
                </th>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <th>
                    TOTAL
                </th>
                <th>
                    <h5 id="ccantidad"></h5>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <h4 id="total">
                        $/ 0.00
                    </h4>
                    <input type="hidden" name="total_venta" id="total_venta">
                    <input type="hidden" name="cantidad" id="cantidad">
                </th>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 text-center" id="guardar">
        <div class="form-group">
            <!--token para poder trabajar con las transaciones de detalle-->
            <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}" />
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="guardar" disabled required>
                Guardar
            </button>
        </div>
```

este es el script que esta en el mismo archivo `create.blade.php` donde se ejcuta el evento calcular

```
<script>
    var m1 = document.getElementById("pcantidad");
    var m2 = document.getElementById("pinteres");
    var boton_de_calcular = document.getElementById("calcular");
    boton_de_calcular.addEventListener("click", total);
    //se habilita el boton submit despues de dar clic al boton calcular, pero no me funciona
    document.getElementById("guardar").disabled = false;

    
    function total() {
    var porcentaje = (m1.value * m2.value)/100;
    var resultado= parseInt(m1.value) + parseInt(porcentaje);
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML= new Intl.NumberFormat("es-CO").format(resultado);
    document.getElementById("total_venta").value = new Intl.NumberFormat("es-CO").format(resultado);
    
    }

function escribir() {
let cantidad = document.getElementById("pcantidad").value;
//Se actualiza en cantidad inm
document.getElementById("ccantidad").innerHTML = new Intl.NumberFormat("es-CO").format(cantidad);
document.getElementById("cantidad").value = new Intl.NumberFormat("es-CO").format(cantidad);
}

</script>
```

este es el archivo donde esta la funcion donde se guarda el registro `CuentaController.php` lo dejo por si lo necesitan.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            //trnsacion de abmos:cuenta y detalle
            DB::beginTransaction();

            //instancia modelo cuenta
            $cuenta             = new Cuenta();
            $cuenta->cliente_id = $request->get('idcliente');
            $cuenta->users_id = $request->get('prestador');
            $mytime             = Carbon::now();
            $cuenta->fecha      = $mytime->toDateString();
            $cuenta->nota       = $request->get('nota');

            //campo agregado q se hara funcion script en el formulario
            $cuenta->total = $request->get('total_venta');
            $cuenta->saldo = $request->get('total_venta');

            $cuenta->save();

            // se recoje los datos de la tabla dettalle cuenta
            $fiador    = $request->get('fiador');
            $cantidad  = $request->get('cantidad');
            $interes   = $request->get('pinteres');

            //se insertan los campos de la tabla ingreso cuenta
            $detalle = new DetalleCuenta();
            //se muestra el autoingreseo generado guardado anteriomente
            $detalle->cuenta_id    = $cuenta->idcuenta;
            // $detalle->prestador_id = $prestador;
            $detalle->fiador_id    = $fiador;
            $detalle->cantidad     = $cantidad;
            $detalle->interes      = $interes;
            $detalle->save();

            //guarda los cambios
            DB::commit();

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            //si alguna falla en guardar una cuenta o detalle se anula la transacion
            DB::rollback();

        }

        return Redirect::to('cuentas/prestamo')->with('message', 'Prestamo creado correctamente');
    }
```

Todo esta funcional pero no he podido colocar el boton requerido para el usuario.

Comment: ¿Y si pones el botón "Guardar" disabled y al hacer clic en el botón "Calcular" se lo quitas?

Comment: Otra posibilidad es hacer los calculos al recibir la informacion y solo tener un boton de Guardar.

Comment: @JosueArriola he intentado pero no me habilita el boton, me podrias orientar?

Comment: Coincido con @KennyBarrera, sería mejor un solo botón "Calcular y guardar" que realice los cálculos y valide toda la información antes de enviar el formulario.

Comment: @Triby si tienes razón estoy intentando pero no me funciona, porfa me pueden orientar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con la ayuda de los comentarios pude resolverlo.

Se le agrega un id al boton calcular

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" id="calcular" type="button">
                Calcular
            </button>
```

Al boton submit se desactiva y se coloca un id

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  id="guardar"  disabled="true">
                Guardar
            </button>
```

Con js se hace la funcion que se necesita con el boton calcular y activa el boton submit

```
 var m1 = document.getElementById("pcantidad");
    var m2 = document.getElementById("pinteres");
    var boton_de_calcular = document.getElementById("calcular");
    boton_de_calcular.addEventListener("click", total);
    
    
    function total() {
    var porcentaje = (m1.value * m2.value)/100;
    var resultado= parseInt(m1.value) + parseInt(porcentaje);
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML= new Intl.NumberFormat("es-CO").format(resultado);
    document.getElementById("total_venta").value = new Intl.NumberFormat("es-CO").format(resultado);
    document.getElementById("guardar").disabled = false;
    }
```